# Update OxyPlots quickly (without slider delay)

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, oxyplot

I have slider, that changes position of annotations in OxyPlot.

[image: slider and oxyplot]

As you can see, it is rather slow. My questions is **how to make it faster** or at least let slider to slide smoothly and change the blue line position on the background?

Here is the complete code I used. Note that step frequency is set to .001 and there are actually multiple plots to make this "issue" more obvious.

**XAML:**

```xml
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ScrollViewer>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" x:Name="stack">
            <!--Here comes the plot from code behind-->
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Slider Width="200" StepFrequency="0.001" ValueChanged="Slider_ValueChanged" Minimum="-1" Maximum="1"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

**Code Behind:**

```cs
List<PlotModel> models = new List<PlotModel>();
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {

        PlotView Plot = new PlotView();
        Plot.Height = 200;
        PlotModel model = new PlotModel();
        models.Add(model);
        model.Series.Add(new FunctionSeries(System.Math.Sin, 0, 10, 0.1, "sin(x)"));
        Plot.Model = model;

        var annotation = new LineAnnotation()
        {
            Type = LineAnnotationType.Horizontal,
            ClipByXAxis = false,
            Y = 0,
        };
        Plot.Model.Annotations.Add(annotation);
        stack.Children.Add(Plot);
    }
}
private void Slider_ValueChanged(object sender, RangeBaseValueChangedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var mo in models)
    {
        (mo.Annotations.First() as LineAnnotation).Y = e.NewValue;
        mo.InvalidatePlot(true);
    }

}
```

### EDIT - Partial solution

With help of @Faywang - MSFT's answer I managed to implement timer and "hide" plot invalidations there. It doesn't solve the slowness of the oxyplot itself, but at least the slider is not dragged down by it:

[image: not so slow annotation]

[The full demo project on GitHub](https://github.com/tesar-tech/OxyplotSlowAnnotation).

```cs
private void Slider_ValueChanged(object sender, RangeBaseValueChangedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var annotation in annotations)
    {
        annotation.X = e.NewValue;
    }
    StartTimer();
}

private DispatcherTimer _annotationTimer;

private void StartTimer()
{
    if (_annotationTimer is null)
    {
        _annotationTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        _annotationTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.01);
        _annotationTimer.Tick += _timer_Tick;

    }
    _annotationTimer?.Start();
}

private void _timer_Tick(object sender, object e)
{
    foreach (var annotation in annotations)
    {
        annotation.PlotModel.InvalidatePlot(false);
    }
    _annotationTimer.Stop();
}
```

Comment: Hi, have you solved your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since multiple renderings in a short time will cause delay, the Slider cannot respond in time. You could try to use a Timer and force redrawing with a fixed time interval(e.g. Here I set the interval as 80ms) when dragging the Slider, it will reduce the number of renders and smoother. For example:

```
private DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer;
public void DispatcherTimerSetup()
{
    dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
    dispatcherTimer.Tick += DispatcherTimer_Tick; ;
    dispatcherTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(80);
    dispatcherTimer.Start();
}

private void DispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, object e)
{
    foreach (var mo in models)
    {
        (mo.Annotations.First() as LineAnnotation).Y = MySlider.Value;
        mo.InvalidatePlot(true);
    }
}

private void Slider_ValueChanged(object sender, RangeBaseValueChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (dispatcherTimer == null)
    {
        DispatcherTimerSetup();
    }
}
```

Or you can call the `Task.Run( )` method to create a task and put time-consuming operations inside, then use await to perform asynchronous operations. When you want to update the UI in this method, you need to use `Dispatcher.RunAsync` method to back to the UI thread.

Comment: I tried. Issue is probably within oxyplot. It is just too slow to redraw the line.. So the "solution" is to increase the timer interval, but it is same as lowering slider step frequency...

Comment: Yes,  the multiple renderings in a short time will cause delay, so we add the time interval. Or you could try to call the Task.Run( ) method put time-consuming operations inside.

Comment: For anybody who's interested in solution, please see the **EDIT** part in original answer.